# Email validation rule in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I do email validation using the simple rule:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
```

How do I modify the option `unique` so that it will work only if the entered email is different from the primordial?

**A sample:**

The field `email` contains the default value from table `users`: `example@gmail.com`

Then I push the button without making any changes in the form I should not check `unique:users`.

Otherwise, if I even changed one symbol in `example@gmail.com1` I must validate the incoming value using: `unique:users`.

Comment: If you send it to the backend - eventhough you did not make changes - you should always check it. If you did not change anything and want a "delta update" you will need smarter rules since required forces you to send it anyways.

You can define different rules for inserting and updating, by this you do not run into the error "unique" on update

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did this using the conditional checks:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), []);

 $validator->sometimes('email', 'unique:users,email', function ($input) {
            return $input->email !== Auth::user()->email;
        });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can find an example here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update

You will need to have multiple rules depending on the request method (update or create) and you can pass a third parameter to unique to ensure no fail if you know the user / email

```
'user.email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
```

Switch for method

```
switch($this->method())
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is as loophole in laravel validation.
I update the code for email validation. This is working fine for me.

```
'email' => [
   'required', 'email:rfc',
   function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
   if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
   }
}],
```